# Media Queries - Should we always set a default value on original/parent stylesheet?

Tags: css, media-queries

On a **mobile-first** design, after changing values with Media Queries, Are we supposed to set them back to their original values on the parent stylesheet? or will it be handled by the browser?

```
<div id="mobile">
 <div class="box1">
 <div class="box2">
 ...
</div>
```

stylesheet:

```
    ( default style for mobile goes here )

@media (min-width: 500px) { 
    .box1 {
    float: right;
    }
    .box2 {
    float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) { 
    .mobile {
    display: none;
    }
}
```

like in this case, should I to set the **display** value to, for example **block** on the *default stylesheet*? and/or reset the **float** attributes respectively?

Comment: On a mobile first stylesheet, all default styles should be for the mobile device, then media quarries should be used for larger screens.

Answer (score 0):

No, setting default values won't be required in this case.

HTML has default **display** property with value **inline**, but say we want default value as **block** then we might want to specify default values.